# Проблемы при переключении раскладки с помощью комбинаций клавиш указанных в gsettings

Tags: debian, fedora, gnome

Использую gnome 40. В настройках gsettings поставил переключение раскладки клавиатуры по клавише capslock. Проблемы когда переключаешь раскладку с помощью комбинаций клавиш указанных в gsettings:

1. значок изменения раскладки в верхнем правом углу не меняется
2. нужно нажать 2 раза на кнопки переключения раскладки, чтобы изменить язык с последнего в списке на 1-ый.(для примера, если каждый раз после переключение языка нажимать на одну и туже клавишу, получится так: jооjооjооj)

Эти проблемы были также и в предыдущих версиях гном, тестировал на разных компьютерах и дистрибутивах.

Также заметил, что если в gsettings назначить переключение раскладки на alt+shift, то перестают работать сочетания включающие в себя alt+shift. Для примера ctrl+shift+alt+arrow_right, alt+shift+tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока писал вопрос, случайно нашёл решение.
Если в gsettings для переключения раскладки (/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options) убрать ключ 'grp:alt_shift_toggle', то всё начинает работать как надо, включая сочетания, использующие alt+shift. Если убрать ключ grp:caps_toggle и оставить grp:alt_shift_toggle, то переключение раскладки тоже начинает работать как надо, но другие сочетания клавиш, использующие alt+shift, не работают.

Кривая какая-то система, но хоть работает) Если кто-то знает как заставить работать всё и сразу, пожалуйста, отпишитесь.